# JQuery Form Validator in Angular2

Tags: jquery, angular

Is it possible to use jQuery Form Validator in Angular2? I have tried with a basic form and found the validations are not happening.

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <form action="" id="testForm" ngNativeValidate>
        <div class="form-group">
            E-mail
            <input name="email"
                   data-validation="email"
                   [(ngModel)]="email"
                   name="Email"
                   #email="ngModel" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            E-mail
            <input name="age"
                   data-validation="required"
                   [(ngModel)]="age"
                   name="Age"
                   #age="ngModel" />
        </div>     
    </form>
</div>
```

and in the type script when I `use $('#testForm').validate()`, nothing is happening. I have installed jquery jquery-validation@1.17.0 and jquery in the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Use Form builder and create your validation in a constructor.

Something like this: https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-form-builder-and-validation-management

Comment: But we need ngModel mapping, if we use form builder by Angular then there is a conflict between formControlName and ngModel, let me know if there are any ways to avoid it.

Comment: @user1058913 what do you mean, I use formControlName="name" [(ngModel)]="something.name", it shouldnt be a problem. If you have problems still, try adding [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"

Comment: When i used both ngModel and formControlName i get this error "There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngModel" "<input type="text"  class="form-control" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" formControlName="Server" id="server" [(ngModel)]="data?.Server.value" name="Server" #server="ngModel"/> <control-messages [control]="dnsForm.controls.dnsServer"></control-messages>